# django template tag url only work when empty url pattern is last

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-templates

iam learning django and there is something i don't quite understand if that's django behavior or iam doing something wrong.
so basically iam trying use django template tag to create a fixed html  header and footer to extend from it the base.html is like this

```
 <a href="{% url "index" %}" style="text-decoration:none;"><h1 style="text-align: center;color: green">Welcome to HireMe</h1></a>
{% block title %}
{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}

<a href="{% url "about" %}" style="text-decoration:none;"><h4 style="text-align: left;color: purple;margin-top:256px;">About us</h4></a>
```

and the index.html is like this

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<body style="background-color: rgb(243,220,245) ">

<div align="center">

    <p>Fugiat commodo officia laborum esse magna nisi commodo eu est non sunt in ut adipisicing nulla cupidatat dolor.</p>
    <img src="https://media4.giphy.com/media/3pZipqyo1sqHDfJGtz/giphy.gif">

</div>
</body>
{% endblock content%}
```

and when i use the url template tag here href="{% url "index" %}" it should take me to the index
page accourding to my naming in url patterns

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('test/', include('pages.urls'), name='test'),
    path('about', include('pages.urls'), name='about'),
    path('', include('pages.urls'), name='index'),
]
```

and it does as long as the "" pattern is last but if i changed the lines to this

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('test/', include('pages.urls'), name='test'),
        path('', include('pages.urls'), name='index'),
        path('about', include('pages.urls'), name='about'), 
    ]
```

it takes me to /about page and if i changed the href="{% url "index" %}" to href="{% url "about" %}" it takes me to /aboutabout page so is the url value is always the last pattern or iam doing something wrong

the pages/url.py file

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import HomePageView, AboutPageView, TestPageView

urlpatterns = [
    path('about', AboutPageView.as_view(), name='about'),
    path('test', TestPageView.as_view(), name='test'),
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='index'),
]
```

views file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.


class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'


class AboutPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'about.html'


class TestPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'test.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

The source of error is you're missing some details of URLs handling in Django, more details about it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/

Your project urls should look like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('pages/', include('pages.urls')),
]
```

or alternatively:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
]
```

if you don't want use prefix `pages` in your urls.

and the pages/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import HomePageView, AboutPageView, TestPageView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('about', AboutPageView.as_view(), name='about'),
    path('test', TestPageView.as_view(), name='test'),
]
```

the url for home will be: `<my_project_url>/pages/` and the about page: `<my_project_url>/pages/about` and so on.

Comment: just edited the question with the file content

Comment: first thanks that's very helpfull... but what if i want to have a default app like i want home page of my website to be the pages app so it's <my_project_url>/about instead of <my_project_url>/pages/about ... i looked at the docs but couldn't really understand this

Comment: Edit my answer to show an alternative to avoid pages prefix in urls.